# Android AlarmClock search by label

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to use an Intent with [android.provider.AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) to dismiss (ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM) an specific Alarm. I want to use ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL to select the alarm. However, I have no idea how I can set the label to search for.

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_ALARM_SEARCH_MODE, AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL);
startActivity(i);
```

Can someone help me complete the code?

Comment: I don't know the code, but it sounds to me like your objective is to find an alarm already scheduled with the platform and the proceed to dismiss it. I think an obstacle here is that you are attempting to start an activity with this intent above. Try looking into the AlarmManager class to see if you can search for a pending intent and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is:

```
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, label)
```

This seems to result in deleting the entry with that label.