# How can I dismiss an alarm with ACTION_DIMISS_ALARM

Tags: android, alarm, dismiss

```
Thread threadDismiss = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                          Intent dismiss = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM);
                          dismiss.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_ALARM_SEARCH_MODE,AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_NEXT);
                          startActivity(dismiss);
                          }
                       });
```

Hello, I'm trying to dismiss the next alarm on my phone.
But when I start my threadDismiss with start(). The alarm is not dismiss and I'm redirect to the alarm UI.

How can I dismiss an alarm with AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM ??

Comment: So.. no one seems to know the answer to this...

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233249/android-alarmclock-search-by-label