# How to modify an existing alarmclock?

Tags: android

I'm facing kinda the same problem as described in this post: [Android AlarmClock search by label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233249/android-alarmclock-search-by-label).

I want to modify an existing alarm if it already exists and add one if it doesn't. I'm using `ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL` in combination with `AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE` to select the alarm, but I'm not sure why it doesn't select the existing alarm.

I am using it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "my alarm");
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_ALARM_SEARCH_MODE, AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL);
startActivity(i);
```

This will just create a new alarm every time I run this piece of code, what extra or action is required to modify an existing one?

[image]

Comment: Based on the amount of replies, it's not an easy thing to do...

Comment: I guess it might be impossible to do...

Comment: Still no answers :(